# Autocomplete jquery not working?

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, webforms, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a text box,
Inside I want it to auto complete.
The data for the auto complete is going to be given through the database.

This is my Jquery:

```
 var data = "autocompletetagdata.aspx"
    $("#item").autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
```

This is what I have put in autocompletetagdata for now:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string term = Request.QueryString["term"];
   SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
   myConnection.Open();
   string SQL = ("select Top 10 LTRIM(RTRIM(PGPRDC)) As PGPRDC FROM SROPRG SROPRG");
   SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, myConnection);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   try
      {
        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
             sb.Append(reader.GetString(0))
                           .Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
      }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      myConnection.Close();
   }
   myConnection.Close();
       Response.Write(sb.ToString());  
//return "['word', 'hello', 'work', 'oi', 'hey']";     
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.sifr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/orderstatus.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/json_parse.js"></script>
```

When you go to autocompletetagdata..aspx in the browser you get back on the screen...

```
SC052 SC053 SC055 SC060 SC061 SC062 SC063 SG011 SG014 SG015
```

Firebug also does show these items being sent back in the response, but nothing happens to the text box

Comment: autocompletetagdata.aspx should return JSON encoded data e.g. `['SC052', 'SC053']` etc. This is what jQuery-ui autocomplete expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Jquery Code :

```
$("#txt1").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",                        
            url: "YourAddress",           
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",                                                    
            success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                return {
                    id: item.Value,
                    value: item.Text
                }
            }))
        }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#hdnId").val(ui.item.id);//Put Id in a hidden field
    }
});
```

call you ajax request and return JSON data something like this :

```
[{"Value":val1,"Text":"text1"},
{"Value":val2,"Text":"text2"}]
```

for return somthing like that you must define a class like this :

```
public class Autocomplete
{

    private int val;
    private string text;

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return val;
        }
        set
        {

            val = value;
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {

            text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

so it just enough to return a list of this class objects (`List<Autocomplete>`).So create this list and fill it by your sqlcommand and then return it as response of your XMLHTTPRequest

I tested it.It works great man

Good luck.Foroughi

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if this works like I think but:
**autocompletetagdata.aspx** may be showing data, but when you do **source: data**, data is not ready, I mean it dont contain data. I solve similiar problem by filling **source** in callback function (here, callback of **autocompletetagdata.aspx**).

Answer (score 0):

I have problem with autocomplete. I reached here because you include qtip. Those two libs (jquery/autocomplete and qtip) have problems when used both.