# jQueryUI Autocomplete is not properly filtering results from a JSON file

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've configured a jQueryUI-powered search with the autocomplete widget on my test site http://karem.kaidez.com/. The data is being populated by a `.json` file and all of the results are appearing when I expected them to be filtered based on what I typed in the search box.

The search box is embedded in the HTML like this:

`<input type="text" id="searchfield" class="searchfield-style" placeholder="Search..." />`

The specific jQueryUI code looks as follows:

```
  define("search", ["jquery","jqui"], function($, jqui) { //running via RequireJS
  $("#searchfield").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "search.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term},
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              label: item.title
            };
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 0,
    select: function(event, ui) {
     //code comes later
    }
  });
});
```

`search.json` looks like this:

```
[

  {
    "title":"lorem",
    "url":"/lorem/"
  },

  {
    "title":"ipsum",
    "url":"/ipsum/"
  },

 false
 /*
  * This 'false' is here because the JSON file is being built via a Jekyll 
  * plugin and adding commas at the end of the final key/value pait.
  * Adding 'false' makes the file valid JSON. 
  */

]
```

I did see this other SO question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843496/jquery-ui-autocomplete-not-filtering-data) and I think I got everything right in terms making sure the term parameter is properly configured. I want to THINK that the fix is easy but am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

    ('#searchfield').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "search.json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {term: request.term},
    success: function(data) {
      response($.map(data, function(item) {
        return {
          label: item.title
        };
      }));
    }
  });
},
        minLength: 2,
        search: function(oEvent, oUi) {
            var selectedValue = $(oEvent.target).val();
            var aSearch = [];
            $('source').each(function(index, value) {
                if (value.substr(0, selectedValue .length) == selectedValue ) 
                    aSearch.push(value);               
            });

            $(this).autocomplete('option', 'source', aSearch);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi PSR...thanks for responding! I tried your code and, unfortunately, I got a console error message that `aCleanData` was not defined.

Comment: Hi PSR...thanks again for the code edit!  Sadly, I still get the same console error message.

Comment: Hi PSR...thanks again! The error message is gone but sadly, the field no longer populates. I did update my original post with my full jQueryUI code, JSON file and how the input field is represented in the HTML.  The URL to the testing site is also there. Thanks again for taking the time...it's appreciated!

Comment: sorry i am unable to find the problem

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734554/how-to-filter-your-jquery-autocomplete-data-while-typing.this might helpful to you

Comment: Thx...will check out the article.